# Building a node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, very basic question.
I just wrote some nodes to (hopefully) turn a servo with a joystick. I used `catkin_create_pkg` to make a package in the src folder. Then I used `catkin_make` to make the package. I made a directory in there, and pasted my two python codes. I used `catkin_make` again. These are the same steps as in the [publisher tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29). when I try to run my nodes, I get

```
: No such file or directory
```

Is there a step I'm missing. I know in the ros tutorials there is alot in the [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) tutorial I didn't understand.

Thanks for the help.

The exact command I ran is

```
donni@donni-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src/pi_servo/scripts$ rosrun pi_servo servo_listener.py
: No such file or directory
```

When I run grep

```
donni@donni-VirtualBox:~$ env|grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

I don't think that looks wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200820/building-a-node/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-01-12**:
It will help us if you edit your question to add the exact command you ran, and the result of `env|grep ROS` command to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

This indicates sourcing `devel/setup.bash` did not work as expected. `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` must contain the path of your catkin workspace in order for your executables to be found by ROS.

I just added a passage to the [create catkin workspace tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace).

```
To make sure your workspace is properly overlayed by the setup script, make sure ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable includes the directory you're in.

    $ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
    /home/youruser/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

So in your case, I suggest to make sure you build and source properly. You can try again by removing the built artifact (see [Cleaning up](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace#Cleaning_up)) and run `catkin_make`, and source the setup.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0